# Consulta SQL tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql

Les agradezco me pueda colaborar con la siguiente inquietud, puede ser algo sencillo pero no he logrado entender como realizarlo:
Supongamos que tengo dos tablas "TABLA1" y "TABLA2" están relacionadas con el campo "CAMPO1". En la TABLA1, CAMPO1 es valor único, mientras en la TABLA2 pueden repetirsen los valores en ese campo. Es decir tengo el valor único 123 en el CAMPO1 de la TABLA1 y en el CAMPO1 de la TABLA2 está varias veces el valor 123.
Lo que quiero es imprimir el valor 123 de TABLA1 CAMPO1 y sobre esa misma iteración imprimir los valores 123 de la TABLA2 CAMPO1 cuantas veces estén.

Ejemplo del resultado básico que espero:
[image: tabla]

Necesito entender eso básico para poder hacer el procedimiento real que es más complejo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! probaste con un join, y cual fue el problema?

Comment: Investiga sobre la clausula inner join

Comment: `select * from tabla1 join tabla2 on tabla1.campo1 = tabla2.campo1`

Comment: *Necesito entender eso básico para poder hacer el procedimiento real que es más complejo.* Pues es mejor que expliques todo, por complejo que sea, porque quizá estás cometiendo errores en el diseño de los datos, y arrastrarás con esos errores hasta que todo se haga tannnn complejo que sea imposible de sostener. O, puede que no sea tan complejo como crees. En fin, explica brevemente todo el contexto y podremos ayudarte mejor.